# How can I eliminate #error in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services

```
=CStr(First(Fields!AXPPaymentTerm.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS")) & vbcrlf & 
iif(First(Fields!AXPSpotRateCurrency.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS") = 1,"",
"Rate of exchange : " &
First(Fields!AXPSpotRateCurrency.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS") & " " &
First(Fields!AXPSpotRate.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS")
)
```

Comment: There is missing information about your report layout and some sample data. Try to seperate your expression in parts and check which parts fail

Comment: The syntax looks correct for the expression. If you use Visual Studio you can Preview the report and check the Error tab for a better error message. You can try CSTR for the other values but SSRS is usually good about mashing different types in a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

=CStr(First(Fields!AXPPaymentTerm.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS")) & vbcrlf &
iif(CStr(First(Fields!AXPSpotRate.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS")) = "1","",
"Rate of exchange : " &
First(Fields!AXPSpotRateCurrency.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS") & " " &
First(Fields!AXPSpotRate.Value, "SalesInvoiceHeaderFooterDS")
)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.